# Buildroot made change on the Linux Kernel, how to avoid full rebuild?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, buildroot

I’m experimenting with linux-kernel/net/ipv4/igmp.c. To compile I use buildroot. When I make a change on igmp.c, is a full rebuid necessary?

> The easiest way to rebuild a single package from scratch is to remove its build directory in output/build. Buildroot will then re-extract, re-configure, re-compile and re-install this package from scratch. You can ask buildroot to do this with the make -dirclean command.

https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#rebuild-pkg

The documentation talks only about packages, but I think it doesn’t include changes on the kernel itself? How can I avoid a full rebuild?

Comment: "*is a full rebuid necessary?*" -- No. "*How can I avoid a full rebuild?*" -- Buildroot uses **make** files, which will automatically "*avoid a rebuild*" unless source changes have been made. You're overthinking this. The Linux kernel is treated as a package, albeit a special one. More likely the issue will be that a recompile is not performed when you want/need it. Always *verify* that changes are actually incorporated in your "latest" build. If not, then you need to explicitly delete the appropriate **.stamp_xxx** status files in the output/build/<package> directory to trigger a rebuild.

Answer (score 1):

Linux is treated like any other package and you can rebuild it with:

```
$ make linux-rebuild
```

This is true for all packages.

`-rebuild` make recipe suffix means something like:

```
$ make all
```

in the build/linux/ package directory.
So if you change a file and issue that command only that file or its dependencies is built again.

Another useful recipe suffix is `-menuconfig` that is also available for `u-boot` (`-rebuild` too).

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest way to force a rebuild of the Linux package (or any other package) is to remove the .stamp_built file in the output/build/linux-version directory. After that just make again and it will be rebuilt and installed.

In my case :

```
rm output/build/linux-v4.19.253/.stamp_built
make
```